# Reuse servlet generated image

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jakarta-ee

I have a JavaScript function which passes variable to servlet, servlet does some calculations and produces a result in image format

```
var x,y,z; 
x="something"; y="something"; z="something";

var image = document.getElementById("finalpic");
image.src ="http://xyz/folder/myservlet1?monthly="+monthly+"&recent="+recent+"&likes="+likes;

 document.body.appendChild(image);
```

In return servlet produces a image which gets loaded,

I need to use url of this dynamic image to another javascript function to make a ajax/jQuery call which requires url of image.

I don't want to produce image twice I want to use already generated image url.

```
FB.api('/me/photos','post', {
    message:'image',
    url:image    
  }, function(response){
```

How can I do this, because even when I open the generated image it get generated again and then show in tab? How to take advantage of already produced image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link and my understanding, I feel caching servlet results is a configuration stuff, and the request is not sent to the server again for processing. Sorry if am wrong about that.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-2634/abxbu/index.html

Comment: You're spot on about the solution: caching, though the link you posted doesn't really apply to JavaEE. It's actually pretty old, try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beagj.html) instead. It's a glassfish-specific config, which leads me to believe there is no uniform way to provide across all containers. Is there?